# Homography matrix for two pictures in 4d space

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have two pictures from Google Street View. Pictures have 4 parameters: the latitude and longitude (from which the picture is made), the horizontal and vertical angle of the camera. Also there are the latitude and longitude of the object, which is depicted in two photographs.

I need to calculate the homography matrix between the pictures.

Standard methods require knowledge of comparable points, but I basically can not have this information. I know that I can find homography matrix through the matrix of rotation and calibration, but can not be generalized to the case of 4-dimensional space (my case).

How can I calculate the homography matrix between these two pictures?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question as it is impossible to generate an homography that relates two real-world images if the images aren't planar. If you want to pretend they are, then try to figure out how you would represent each of these parameters in terms of a transformation matrix. E.g. what would a square look like if you viewed it from an angle? It would look like a trapezoid. What about if you were closer to it in lat/long? It would scale larger. Homographies have 8 degrees of freedom; you need to figure out how many parameters in an homography your 4 parameters translate to.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Thank you for comment! Based on information about coordinates, I can calculate the distances from cameras to object and translate. Based on information about angles, I can estimate rotation. What I can do next step?

Comment: Not quite...if you're working with street view images, then coordinates give you translation of x values only when you're viewing the exact side of the road. Otherwise coordinates will also scale things if you're facing forwards. If you only have hoz and vert pitch angles, then you won't get any rotation of the images, but instead hoz or vert distortions. Can you be more specific with example images? You cannot use regular homographies to stitch spherical images, so I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds https://ibb.co/faXQ7F
https://ibb.co/kj6rga, 1 pic - latitude 55.704767,longitude 37.527403,127.19 degress horizontal angle of camera,18.91 degrees vertical angle of camera., 2 pic - latitude 55.704723,longitude 37.527696,134.61 degress horizontal angle of camera,16.62p degrees vertical angle of camera. Object - big building, coordinates - 55.700332, 37.529434. I want to estimate homography between 2 pics for transform building on 1 pic to building on 2 pic.